# Sitecore XPath syntax for the ancestor just below root?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find ancestor-or-self that is a child of an element with particular attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341216/how-to-find-ancestor-or-self-that-is-a-child-of-an-element-with-particular-attri)

How do you select the ancestor just one level below Home? Say the current node is Home/**News**/moreType/2010/09/NewsItem1, and I want to get **News**. ( Under Home there can be landing section page like News or other type of nodes like common Folder)     So far I've tried - **ran the queries in XPath Builder, with context node set to NewsItem1**
:

- `ancestor::*[position() = last() - 1]` syntax error, although
  `ancestor::*[last()]` does seem to return Home
- `ancestor::*[@@parentid='{home guid}']` having issue with @@parentid see my [other
  question and comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719704/does-parentid-attribute-work-in-sitecore-query)
- `(ancestor::*[position() < last()])[last()]` syntax error

The problem I'm trying to solve is: locate the landing section parent of any "page" under Home, for highlighting navigation menu purpose. I've referenced [Sitecore Query Syntax](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Using%20Sitecore%20Query/Sitecore%20Query%20Syntax.aspx)(and learned some interesting query details, like `/ancestor-or-self::*[@#More Criteria Field#!='']/.[1]` actually works), but I'm stuck here.

Thanks for your time and inputs.

Comment: `ancestor::*[position() = last() - 1]`, or shorter `ancestor::*[last()-1]`, are both valid XPath expressions that should work.

Comment: @choroba: yes they are valid XPath expression but Sitecore Query isn't equivalent to XPath, see my reference link. So it's difficult not knowing what's supported and what's not.

Comment: While the suggested queries look correct, none of them actually work in the XPathBuilder. I'm also finding that the query is returning the Home node, and not the node we're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ancestor::*[parent::Home]
```

(Sorry, if you're using some non-standard variant of XPath in which this isn't supported, then I can't help you. - if it's not an XPath question, please change the title).

Comment: Elegant solution. (Yes Sitecore query isn't standard Xpath, thanks to Dimitre for removing tag.) Although in Sitecore this gives me Home, ancestor::*[parent::AnotherNodeSameLevelWithNews] gives me News. Weird but it must be a Sitecore problem.

Answer (score 2):

See here

[How to find ancestor-or-self that is a child of an element with particular attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341216/how-to-find-ancestor-or-self-that-is-a-child-of-an-element-with-particular-attri)

ancestor-or-self::*[parent::item[@key='key of root item']]

Comment: thanks. Like `ancestor::*[parent::Home]` from the other answer, `ancestor-or-self::*[parent::*[@@id='{my-Home-Guid}']]` gives me Home, not the level below.  ( Also you were parsing a standard xml document, while I query Sitecore content tree with XPath Builder which may be a little different. )

Comment: Actually, I was querying Siteocre content tree, but tried to make the question as generic as possible! ancestor-or-self will ensure that if you're already on your landing page you still select it. Specifying [parent::item[@key='home']] means that the item you select will have the home item as parent, so will return your landing page.